# python reshape structure array to normal numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a structure array which looks like this

```
[(1, 2, 3, 4) (5, 6, 7, 8)]
```

and I removed the first column and make it looks like this

```
[(2, 3, 4) (6, 7, 8)]
```

but when I reshape it to array, it looks like this

```
[[1 2 3 4]
 [5 6 7 8]]
```

the '1' and '5' was not supposed to be there

This is my code

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([(1,2,3,4), (5,6,7,8)],dtype=[('a', 'i4'), ('b', 'i4'), ('c', 'i4'),('d', 'i4')])
names = list(array.dtype.names)
new_names=names[1:]
data = array[new_names]
new_array = data.view('i4').reshape(len(data),-1)
```

can I know why and how to edit it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [128]: array = np.array([(1,2,3,4), (5,6,7,8)],dtype=[('a', 'i4'), ('b', 'i4'), ('c', '
     ...: i4'),('d', 'i4')]) 
     ...: names = list(array.dtype.names) 
     ...: new_names=names[1:] 
     ...: data = array[new_names]                                                         
In [129]: array.dtype                                                                     
Out[129]: dtype([('a', '<i4'), ('b', '<i4'), ('c', '<i4'), ('d', '<i4')])
In [130]: names                                                                           
Out[130]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
In [131]: data                                                                            
Out[131]: 
array([(2, 3, 4), (6, 7, 8)],
      dtype={'names':['b','c','d'], 'formats':['<i4','<i4','<i4'], 'offsets':[4,8,12], 'itemsize':16})
```

Note that the `data.dtype` has `offsets`.  In the latest `numpy` versions, selecting a subset of the fields produces a `view`.  `array['a']` is still there, just 'hidden'.

Along with that change, they've added some some functions to the `recfunctions`:

```
In [133]: import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rf
```

To make a copy without the 'a' data:

```
In [134]: data1 = rf.repack_fields(data)                                                  
In [135]: data1                                                                           
Out[135]: 
array([(2, 3, 4), (6, 7, 8)],
      dtype=[('b', '<i4'), ('c', '<i4'), ('d', '<i4')])
```

and to make an unstructured array:

```
In [136]: rf.structured_to_unstructured(array)                                            
Out[136]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]], dtype=int32)
In [137]: rf.structured_to_unstructured(data)                                             
Out[137]: 
array([[2, 3, 4],
       [6, 7, 8]], dtype=int32)
In [138]: rf.structured_to_unstructured(data1)                                            
Out[138]: 
array([[2, 3, 4],
       [6, 7, 8]], dtype=int32)
```

These functions are documented at:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html#accessing-multiple-fields

Since all fields have the same dtype ('i4') `view` works - to a degree

```
In [142]: data.view('i4')                                                                 
Out[142]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], dtype=int32)
In [143]: data1.view('i4')                                                                
Out[143]: array([2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8], dtype=int32)
```

But it's a view of the base data, and the shape is messed up.  This shape issue existing in earlier versions.  So it's best to read up on the changes, and use the recommended functions.

In previous SO questions I might have recommended using a list as intermediary:

```
In [144]: data.tolist()                                                                   
Out[144]: [(2, 3, 4), (6, 7, 8)]
In [145]: np.array(data.tolist())                                                         
Out[145]: 
array([[2, 3, 4],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try slicing at the end:

```
new_array = data.view('i4').reshape(len(data),-1)[:,1:]
```

Result:

```
[[2 3 4]
 [6 7 8]]
```

Comment: [[2, 3, 4]
 [6, 7, 8]] but this is what i wan, without ()

Comment: This is still a structured array, just with a (2,1) shape instead of (2,).

Comment: Instead of double transpose, use a column slice: `[:,1:]`